# Implement complex unicode emoji characters in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate messaging in whatsapp web and on my messages, use some cool emojis, but as you know, chromedriver by default to not type emoji characters with `send_keys()`.

So for testing, my code is based on this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52311893/6580518), which it is working fine, but if I try to send a multiple unicode emoji, this error shows up:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing command parameters
```

Sample of my current code:

```
chatBox = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')
time.sleep(2)
chatBox.click()     
        
JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
elm.value += txt;
elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
"""
text = u'\uD83D\uDC6A'
#using this emoji, it works  
#text = u'\u263A'

self.driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, chatBox, text)
chatBox.send_keys(text)
```

Why is this happening?

---

**Edit 1 - full code with suggested changes to help debbuging**

```
self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
# time to scan qrcode
time.sleep(8)
contact = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='<NAME_OF_SAVED_CONTACT>']")
contact.click()

chatBox = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3uMse")))
chatBox.click()     

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
elm.value += txt;
elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
"""
text = u'\uD83D\uDC6A'
self.driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, chatBox, text)
chatBox.send_keys(text)
```

Answer (score -2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing command parameters
```

...implies that the arguments passed to a command are either invalid or malformed.

---

Invalid argument errors are majorly linked to [TypeErrors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) in JavaScript and they can occur when the input value is not of the expected type or malformed in some way. Possibly in this usecase the issue was the `chatBox` wasn't **interactable** when you tried to send the **emoji** through `execute_script()`.

---

### Solution

A probable solution would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- CodeBlock:

  ```
  chatBox = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3uMse")))
  chatBox.click()     

  JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """
  text = u'\uD83D\uDC6A'
  self.driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, chatBox, text)
  chatBox.send_keys(text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

However, this code block works just perfect at my end to send **complex emoticons** (Emoji) with multiple unicodes e.g. family  using `u\uD83D\uDC6A` as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q")))
  JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
    var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
    elm.value += txt;
    elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    """
  text = u'\uD83D\uDC6A'
  driver.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, element, text)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: emoji_chrome]

---

### Note

Finally, it's worth to mention that https://web.whatsapp.com/ elements are [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled elements. So *classes* like `_3uMse` are dynamically generated and are never static. You may require to construct the locators based on static attributes.

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to click on a username within web.whatsapp.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898797/how-to-click-on-a-username-within-web-whatsapp-com-using-selenium-and-python/61901500#61901500)

Additionally as per the discussion in [Element Send Keys to file input with 'multiple' attribute should append file list](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2721) you need to ensure that your [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) version is at least of **ChromeDriver-75**.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Chromedriver only supports characters in the BMP error while sending Emoji with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium Python to Tkinter's label() textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138825/chromedriver-only-supports-characters-in-the-bmp-error-while-sending-emoji-with/59139690#59139690)
- [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP while sending an emoji through C# Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c/53810992#53810992)

---

### Outro

A couple of relevant discussions in ChromeDriver forum:

- [When input parameter is missing or malformed, ChromeDriver response is not spec compliant](https://monorail-prod.appspot.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2719)
- [sendKeys() sometimes doesn't enter all the characters from string](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1771)

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer @DebanjanB, but unfortunately the error persists, I guess it's something with the WhatsApp web which in trying to automate on, because the example with google worked perfectly! I just edited my question and added the full code to help

Comment: @JoãoVitor Checkout the answer update. Possibly the referenced discussion [How to click on a username within web.whatsapp.com using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898797/how-to-click-on-a-username-within-web-whatsapp-com-using-selenium-and-python/61901500#61901500) will solve your issue.