Selenium chrome webdriver deletes unicode characters
i have a twitter bot which some of his tweets require flags. untill recently, i used tweepy so i had no problem whatsoever. however, due to API access changes, i switched to using selenium webdriver to tweet. this is the code for tweeting (which i import and call for the actual use, and running as main for tests):
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import config
class TweeterChromeConnector:

    def __init__(self):
        # open chrome
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def login(self, user_name, password):
        try:
            # send user
            span_element = self.wait.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Phone, email address, or username']")))
            input_element = span_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'r-')]/following::input")
            input_element.send_keys(user_name)

            # press Next
            span_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Next']")
            button_element = span_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor::span[contains(@class, 'r-')]")
            button_element.click()

            # handle password
            span_element = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Password']")))
            input_element = span_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'r-')]/following::input")
            input_element.send_keys(password)

            # click login
            span_element = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Log in']")))
            button_element = span_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor::span[contains(@class, 'r-')]")
            button_element.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred during login: {e}")
            raise

    def post_tweet(self, post_txt):
        try:
            # Locate the tweet button and wait until it is clickable
            post_button = self.wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-testid='SideNav_NewTweet_Button']"))
            )
            post_button.click()

            # Write tweet
            placeholder_element = self.wait.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='tweetTextarea_0_label']"))
            )
            input_element = placeholder_element.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                             "//div[@class='public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr']")

            # Click on the input element to focus it
            ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(input_element).send_keys(post_txt).perform()

            # Locate the post button and wait until it is clickable
            post_button = self.wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='tweetButton']"))
            )

            # Wait until the button is enabled
            self.wait.until(lambda driver: post_button.is_enabled())
            post_button.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = TweeterChromeConnector()
    tc.login(user_name=config.TWITTER_USER_NAME, password=config.TWITTER_PASSWORD)
    tc.post_tweet('check eng ')
    tc.post_tweet('check sct ')
    tc.post_tweet('check wls ')
    print('done')

however, when trying to tweet the text as shown above ('check eng ', 'check sct ', 'check wls ') i run into a problem. the three flags here are the unicode representations of the actual emojis, and they keep getting 'deleted' (as it seems), when trying to tweet, result in the tweet being just the text ('check eng' instead of 'check eng '), as shown in the attached video1.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915646/7451892

thanks! it worked
